# Как решить данную задачу?

Tags: javascript

Функция `getLeaders` принимает массив чисел, и возвращает массив лидеров

Пояснение: Число считается лидером, если оно больше суммы всех элементов справа от него.

Примечания:

Входной массив содержит не менее 3 элементов
Массив входных чисел может содержать как положительные, так и отрицательные числа
Числа могут повторяться
Массив который возвращается, должен содержать числа в том же порядке, в котором они встречаются в начальном массиве
Отсутствие элементов справа от числа расценивается как 0

Примеры:

```
getLeaders([1, 2, 3, 4, 0]) // Возвращает: [4]

getLeaders([16, 17, 4, 3, 5, 2]) // Возвращает: [17, 5, 2]
```

Мой код:

```js
function getLeaders(numbers) {
  const leader = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    let sumValuesRight = 0;

    for (let v = numbers[i + 1]; v < numbers.length; v++) {
      sumValuesRight += numbers[v];
    }

    if (numbers[i] > sumValuesRight) {
      leader.push(numbers[i]);
    };
  };

  return leader;
}

console.log(getLeaders([1, 2, 3, 4, 0]));
console.log(getLeaders([16, 17, 4, 3, 5, 2]));
console.log(getLeaders([-1,-29,-26,-2]));
```

Comment: Если код написали - в чём вопрос? Если не так работает, то приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: Function 'getLeaders' should work with positive numbers and single leader input: [1,2,3,4,0]
Ожидалось: [4]
Получено: []

Comment: Function 'getLeaders' should work with positive numbers and multiple leaders input: [16,17,4,3,5,2]
Ожидалось: [17,5,2]
Получено: [16,17,4,3,5,2]

Comment: Function 'getLeaders' should work with negative numbers and single leader input: [-1,-29,-26,-2]

Ожидалось: [-1]
Получено: []

Comment: Function 'getLeaders' should work with mixed numbers and single leader input: [5,-2,0]

Ожидалось: [5]
Получено: []

Comment: В вопрос поместите это. И смените название на что-то типа "Неверно работает код, в чем проблема?" + пишите по-русски.

Comment: @КонстантинЖевжик Очень рекомендую вам поместить ваш код в встроенный Code Snippet, чтобы другие люди могли запустить ваш код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам не нужен цикл в цикле, можете просто пройтись по массиву в обратном порядке проверять и складывать по очереди:

```js
const getLeaders = (nums) => {
  let sum = 0;
  const leads = [];
  
  for(let i = nums.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    const num = nums[i];
    
    if (num > sum) leads.push(num);
    sum += num;
  }
  
  return leads.reverse();
}

console.log(getLeaders([1, 2, 3, 4, 0]));
console.log(getLeaders([16, 17, 4, 3, 5, 2]));
```

Comment: Спасибо! 

Нашел и у себя ошибку, и тоже работает:
`for (let v = i + 1; v < numbers.length; v++)`